# How can I grant different rights to a group of users based on the ownership of a file

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2008-r2, network-share, file-permissions

[disclaimer : I'm not a sysadmin, I'm a programmer and I know very little on Windows Administration]

I have a windows Server 2008 R2 machines that share a directory on C:\SDCN with several windows 7 clients.

I have an active directory setup which defines 3 groups of users :
 - Users
 - SuperUsers
 - Adminitrators

In that shared directory there is a subdirectory C:\SDCN\Macro, where users can save their macros for some propietary application.

I'd like any user in the Users group to be able to create, save and modify his own macros, and read all the macro, but not be able to edit the macros of others.
I'd also like any superuser from the SuperUsers group to be able to create save modify and read his own macros AND anyone else's macros, and to take ownership of any macro.

So I figure I should grant full access to SuperUser Group on the macro directory. But what authorization should I grant the Users group on such directory ? and how can I set the authorization of the files in that directory to be dependent on the ownership of the file ?

Is such a thing even possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you should add to permissions list "CREATOR OWNER" user and give to it full permission, also add Users group with read permission.

You can read about "creator owner" more [here](http://networkadminkb.com/KB/a80/creator-owner-explained.aspx).